# Set up Firebird with shared storage?

Tags: firebird

I am new to firebird and confused with SuperServer SuperClassic thing.

But what i wonder is how should i set up this scenario on Linux?

1. Single shared storage that store database file on SAN
2. 4 firebird VPSes connect to the shared storage via NFS
3. a load balancer vps ( any suggestion?)

My system will be 50:50 read : write with transaction. What kind of server should i choose? SC, SS or mix?

Thank you!

Comment: One database can only be accessed by a single database server. SuperClassic, SuperServer is irrelevant here as it only defines how the server process internally works. Databases should never be stored on a shared filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one cpu on the server you need to use Super Classic

http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/qsg25-classic-or-super.html

Also we need more info on the arhitecture that you want to create 
I would avoid point 2 (firebird doesn't work on shared nfs)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on Super Classic, @Mariuz

What do you suggest to setup a shared storage for Firebird? I'm still wonder in case it's not going to work on shared NFS. (I've done successfully with PostgreSQL before)

Comment: @WorajedtS: using a single shared storage for multiple database instances is certainly not possible in Postgres (and I don't think it's possible in Firebird either) so I don't understand what exactly you want to do. Of course you can store the database files on a SAN (although it's probably not a good idea) but that can still be accessed only by a single server process.